# How to run a function when post is edited or updated using publish post action?

Tags: posts, actions, publish

I want to run a **function A()** when a post is published and **function B()** when the same post is edited or updated.

For this, I found *publish_post* action which is triggered whenever a post is published, or if it is edited and the status is changed to publish.

How can I use this *publish_post* action to know that post has been edited or updated so that I can run **function B()**?

Answer (score 2):

With the `post_updated` hook you can trigger an action when the post is updated. He passes 3 parameters:

- `$post_ID` (the post ID),
- `$post_after`(the post object after the edit),
- `$post_before` (the post object before the edit)

Here's an example:

```
<?php
function check_values($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before){
    echo 'Post ID:';
    var_dump($post_ID);

    echo 'Post Object AFTER update:';
    var_dump($post_after);

    echo 'Post Object BEFORE update:';
    var_dump($post_before);
}

add_action( 'post_updated', 'check_values', 10, 3 ); //don't forget the last argument to allow all three arguments of the function
?>
```

See reference [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated)

Comment: The codex says use this hook whenever you need to compare values before and after the post update.

Comment: Yes, it's main function is for that, but nothing stops you to use for your purpose.

Comment: Can you show me a dummy code using this hook?

Comment: @busyjax Sure, the code in my answer works.. just put that in your `functions.php` and you will see that the `var_dumps` will show the content of the posts, including the `$post_id` that you're trying to get

Comment: No, I am asking where do I need to define my function B.

Comment: Your functionB is the function that you will pass to the second parameter in the `add_action`. Ex: `add_action( 'post_updated', 'functionB', 10, 3 );`

Comment: How about using post status transitions?

Comment: If you mean as the other answer, that should work too.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with save_post hook.

Example similar to code in [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

```
function run_my_function( $post_id ) {
  if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){
    // if post udpated
  } else {
    //if is new post
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'run_my_function' );
```

Comment: It is working in both cases.

Comment: $post_id where does it come from

Comment: In BenB's answer? It's passed into the function by the code that calls the save_post filter.

Comment: @MehmetCemil don't post comments as solutions, even if you don't have the reputation to post comments. You'll get banned by the automation as a spammer. I recommend reading about hooks/actions/filters